# setting String formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Whats wrong with formula string below:

L1 is a fixed date and F2 is also date changes with each cell F2,F3, F4...F15

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Data As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")

Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

        ' Whats wrong here, L1 is fixed constant value and  F2, F3,F4,F5,F6...F15
        strFormulas(1) = "= Range("L1").Value - F2"


        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison").Range("G2").Formula = strFormulas
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison").Range("G2:G15").FillDown


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to write the following formula into a cell:
`= Range("L1").Value - F2`
That's not going to work. I believe you might be looking for something like this:

```
strFormulas(1) = "=" & Range("L1").Value & " - F2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the easiest way to figure out what a formula would look like in code is to write it into the worksheet and then look at the formula property in code.

The following would probably do what you want:

```
strFormulas(1) = "=$L$1-F2"
```

Yours doesn't work because you are putting the literal "Range("L1").value" into a worksheet formula, and not the actual value of L1 which is what I think you want.

**EDIT:**
Although your question was only about your formula string, your method of applying it to the cells is also incorrect.

Since you are applying it only to a single cell, you should only use a single element of your array.  (It will work the way you have it, but it is inefficient).  In other words, make the change in your line below.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison").Range("G2").Formula = strFormulas(1)
```

Comment: Not giving desired results:(

Comment: @user3051677 Not useful information since you have not shown your data, results, desired results or how the results differ, nor how you applied the solution.

Comment: @user3051677  The formula subtracts the value in `Fn` from the value in `L1`.  Is that not what you want?